# Redragon gaming mouse not recognizing Button[N] Mouse

Tags: mouse

I have a Mouse Gamer Redragon Impact M908 that has 12 buttons on the side but Blender is not recognizing those buttons. It should be like `Button4 Mouse` but it only recognizes as 4. In the driver, the button is set to "Single Key" `4` and I couldn't find an option like `Button4 Mouse`.
I discover that `Backward` in the driver is recognized as `Button4 Mouse` and `Forward` as `Button5 Mouse` but I don't know how to configure the other 10 buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 7 universally recognized mouse inputs - <kbd>LMB</kbd>, <kbd>RMB</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Up</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Down</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Button</kbd>, <kbd>MB4</kbd>, <kbd>MB5</kbd>.

All of the additional buttons on your mouse are known as *Macro Keys*. These buttons aren't recognized by software, so the manufacturer creates a program that recognizes these inputs, then maps out the input to other known inputs. For example, you can reassign the <kbd>12</kbd> button on your mouse so that when you press it, the system thinks that you pressed <kbd>F12</kbd>. Macros can also simulate a combination of keys, or include delays between inputs.

For your specific mouse, go download the software from https://www.redragonzone.com/pages/download.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, I have found a solution, I have same mouse I will write suddenly to help someone. The proprietary software has the ability to record macros, and macros have the ability to emulate button presses Xbutton4 and Xbutton5. Thus, first we record a macro for pressing and pressing the XB4 and XB5 buttons, and then we hang these macros wherever we want. The advantage of this method is that now other programs, including games, begin to correctly identify these buttons. This suits me, as for the remaining buttons, they will need to be hung on the keyboard keys. As mentioned above, it will not be possible to add more than two additional buttons yet, even if you have the whole mouse in the add. buttons.